# Filter Ionic cards by stored firebase preferences

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a firestore database with 2 different collections of objects, Users & Property. I want to be able to show to a user the relevant property cards in a property feed based on their stored preferences (ie. if their City preference is saved as "Dublin", they are only shown Properties which are located in Dublin).

My property feed component currently looks like this:`

```
export class PropertyFeedComponent implements OnInit {

  Propertys;
  filtered;

  Property: Observable<any[]>;


  filter = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(
    public db: DbService,
    public modal: ModalController,
    public auth: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Propertys = this.auth.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user =>
        this.db.collection$('Propertys', ref =>
          ref
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            .limit(100)
        )
      ),
      shareReplay(1)
    );

   // this.filtered = this.filter.pipe(
    //  switchMap(status => {
    //    return this.Propertys.pipe(

    //    );
    //  })
   // );
  }
}
```

`
I have a filtered function commented out as I'm unsure if this is the best method to go about it.
I call the property's from the database in my HTML like so:

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="(auth.user | async) || {} as user">


  <ion-card *ngFor="let Property of Propertys | async; trackBy: trackById">
```

How do I go about querying each individual object to see if it matches the users stored preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Propertys = this.auth.user$.pipe(
  switchMap(user =>
    this.db.collection$('Propertys', ref =>
      ref
        .where('location','==',user.prefferedlocation)
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .limit(100)
    )
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Where *location* is the field in the *Property* collection.
And *User.prefferedlocation* is where you are storing the preference of user in your Firestore database.

You can either get the preference everytime when the function is called or get the preference saved in local variable of browser to avoid unnecessary reads to your database.